# Kafka string to Dataframe - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I have a Kafka producer:

```py
producer = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
producer.send('topic', ('12', 'AB DD', 'targer_1', '18'))
producer.send('topic', ('33', 'CC FF', 'target_2', '23'))
```

And a Spark consumer what should process this stream:

```py
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCountw")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 4)
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topic, {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

Please help me to transform this stream into a queryable JSON
where the key value structure is something like that:

```py
{"A": '12', "B": 'AB DD', "C": 'targer_1', "D": '18'}
```

I would like to filter the object stream like:

```py
Df.select("A", "C").where("D > 19")
```

And send it back to Kafka.
If you have any suggestion I would happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier for you to use Structured Streaming and full JSON encoding. Write data as JSON

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, to_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *

producer = KafkaProducer(
   value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(dict(zip(["A", "B", "C", "D"], v))).encode('utf-8')
)
```

Read with Spark Kafka reader (you'll have to include `spark-sql-kafka` package):

```py
df = (spark.readStream.format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
   .option("subscribe", "topic")
   .load())
```

Define schema:

```py
schema = StructType([StructField(c, StringType()) for c in ["A", "B", "C", "D"]])
```

Parse, filter and write

```py
(df
    # Parse JSON
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value"))
    # Filter
    .where(col("value.D").cast("integer") > 19)
    # Serialize to JSON
    .select(to_json("value").alias("value"))
    # And write
    .writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("topic", output_topic)
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpont_directory)
    .start())
```

With old API you can:

- Use can use `valueDecoder` or `messageHandler` arguments for `createDirectStream` to decode incoming data. You can also use `map`.
- Use `foreachPartition` to:

  - Convert transformed data to `DataFrame`.
  - Filter out records.
  - Start producer.
  - Write to Kafka.